# Concatenating user-defined variables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three user defined variables, and have only figured out how to concatenate at most, two at a time by performing the following query.

`SET @sql := (CONCAT(@sql_q1, ' UNION ', @sql_med));`

I also want to concatenate my other user-defined variable, @sql_q3, Such that @sql stores @sql_q1, @sql_med and @sql_q3.

Is there a way in which I can concatenate three user defined variables similar to above?

All three variables use the same data from the same table. So joining them isn't an issue, as I can mix and match two variables at a time by using my union line above.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you give an example of the value of each variable?

Comment: sql_q1 holds 58, sql_med holds 116 and sql_q3 holds 172. They are the lower quartile, median and upper quartile from a column that has values from 1 to 230.

Comment: Try: `SET @\`sql_q1\` := 'SELECT 58', @\`sql_med\` := 'SELECT 116', @\`sql_q3\` := 'SELECT 172'; SET @\`sql\` := (CONCAT(@\`sql_q1\`, ' \`quartile\` UNION ', @\`sql_med\`, ' UNION ', @\`sql_q3\`));`

Comment: Your solution works well, but Gordon's will get the vote for neatness. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CONCAT_WS()`:

```
SET @sql := CONCAT_WS(' UNION ', @sql_q1, @sql_med, @sql_q3);
```

Note:  I would recommend that you use `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`.

Also, if one or more of the variables are `NULL`, then it string will still look okay.